# Webhook and WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, api, webhooks

I've posted couple of questions before regarding webhook and wordpress integration but didn't get answers to it. So I am reposting my requirements to see if anyone can help.

So My requirements are :
1) Create new user when I receive webhook submission from thirdparty website like yext.com
2) Update user from submission data.

and I want to build one plugin and handle all this stuffs in that how do I do that ?

For starting I've created one plugin called `yext_update` placed it in plugin directory and created one file in it `yext_update.php`.

On my yext.com account I've configured the webhook url to be `http://mysites.com/wp-content/plugins/yext_update/yext_update.php`.

Next I am handling response data in `yext_update.php` using below code :

```
$webhook_posted_json = file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$location_info = json_decode($webhook_posted_json, true);
```

Next how do I use this json_decoded data to register new user or update user ?
Can you help me do that please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a user in WP with [`wp_create_user`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user).

Similarly, there is a [`wp_update_user`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/).